# fabric.js | Check if mouse is down error

Tags: javascript, jquery, mouseevent, fabricjs

I get the following error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'setFill' of null

I am using fabric.js and the error occurs in the "options.target.setFill()..." line:

```
var mDown = false;
canvas.on('mouse:down', function(options) {
    mDown = true;
});
canvas.on('mouse:up', function(options) {
    mDown = false;
});
canvas.on('mouse:move', function(options) {
    if (mDown == true) {
        options.target.setFill('red');
        canvas.renderAll();
    }
});
```

Without the if condition, the "mouse:move" event works.

Comment: have you tried to check the value of options parameter? via console.log or something..

Comment: it just logs "Null"

Comment: that is the reason why you are getting that error. also can you check the value of canvas if it still have value?

Comment: the canvas still has its values

Comment: so do you want to set fill red whenever you mouse:move the canvas?

Comment: Fill the object under the cursor red, when i mouse:move over the canvas, which i got to work, only if i wrap the setFill part around an if clause, it doesnt work.

Comment: Kindly refer to my answer post below. there is an if condition inside the `object:moving`. I think the object you want to select is not in the `options.target` which you need to specify. You said that you are getting null when you console.log the `options` parameter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must not be clicking on an object. Target is only set if you click an object. below I add a check to see if target is set. without that check I get the same error you explained.

You could also update your code to not listen to the canvas for click events and instead attach the event to the object themselves.

```js
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas("c");

var mDown = false;

canvas.on('mouse:down', function(options) {
    mDown = true;
});
canvas.on('mouse:up', function(options) {
    mDown = false;
});
canvas.on('mouse:move', function(options) {
    if (mDown == true && options.target) {
        options.target.setFill('red');
        canvas.renderAll();
    }
});
```

```css
canvas {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="c" width="400" height="300"></canvas>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/1.6.3/fabric.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: the check for a target gets rid of the error(which isnt the point), but i still dont know why the error is only thrown, once i put an if loop around that line.

Comment: would be great if you could add a working bit of code that showed your problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you need is `object:moving` not `mouse:move` event since `mouse:move` is triggered when you move your mouse point to the canvas, since no object is selected in you canvas, you get null.

take a look for the code below. I created a triangle and every time I moved it, it change its color. Hope you have an idea from this.

```js
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c');
  var mDown = false;
  var triangle = new fabric.Triangle({
    width: 20, height: 30, fill: 'blue', left: 50, top: 50
  });
  canvas.add(triangle);

  canvas.on('mouse:up', function(options) {
    mDown = false;
    triangle.set('fill', 'blue');
  });

  canvas.on('mouse:down', function(options) {
    mDown = true;
    //triangle.set('fill', 'blue');
  });
  
 canvas.on('object:moving', function(options) {
     if (mDown == true)
        triangle.set('fill', 'red');
//triangle.set('fill', 'red');
//canvas.add(triangle);
  });
```

```css
canvas {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/1.6.3/fabric.min.js"></script>

<canvas id="c" width="400" height="300"></canvas>
```